# AWS SageMaker, describe a specific training job using python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

Using SageMaker python SDK I've created an hyper-param tuning job, which runs many jobs in parallel to search for the optimal HP values.

The jobs complete and I get the best training job name as a string "Job...".
I've found the [following article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTrainingJob.html) about how to describe a job using the AWS-CLI or http request.

Is there a way of doing it using the python SageMaker SDK, in order to avoid the complexity of an authenticated request to AWS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a [`sagemaker.session.Session`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/session.py#L70) instance, you can [describe training jobs](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/session.py#L1519):

```
import sagemaker


sagemaker_session = sagemaker.session.Session()
sagemaker_session.describe_training_job("Job...")
```

Comment: Wow this is it. I was very confused when approaching from the python SDK for `describe` method of [AutoMLJob](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/automl.html?highlight=DescribeAutoMLJob#sagemaker.automl.automl.AutoMLJob.describe)